# Pandas dataframes containing special characters

Tags: pandas, unicode, encoding

I am working with a dataset that contains demographic information of Spanish provinces, whose names have special characters such as á,é,í and so on. I am having a hard time with the encoding part of these characters and I would thank any help you could provide me.

So first of all, I figured out that my dataset comes encoded in "latin-1", so I loaded it accordingly and looked for a province with a special character:

```
Population=pd.read_csv('Population.csv',sep='\t',encoding='latin1')
Name_0=Population.iloc[600]['Provincias']                         
print Name_0, type(Name_0)
```

This is my output:

```
Málaga <type 'unicode'>
```

Now, my problem is that I cannot find the way to address the demographic information about "Málaga" in the dataset, because it has the special character "á" on its name. That is, if I try this:

```
Test_0=Population[ Population['Provincias']==u"Málaga"]
```

I get this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So then I try to see what happens if I encode the name of the province in latin-1:

```
Name_1=Name_0.encode('latin-1')
Test_1=Population[ Population['Provincias']==Name_1]
```

but I get an empty dataframe and a warning I do not understand very well:

```
/home/sergio/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py:1603: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
result = libops.scalar_compare(x, y, op)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Provincias, Year, Total]
Index: []
```

So essentially I am not able to access information using the original names of the provinces if they have special characters on their names and I don't know why this happens.
Does anybody know how I could solve this issue?

Edit:
I am using python 2 on ubuntu 18 and emacs for coding.
Also, here's a sample of my dataset:

```
    Provincias  Year      Total
598     Madrid  2001  5.372.433
599     Madrid  2000  5.205.408
600     Málaga  2019  1.661.785
601     Málaga  2018  1.641.121
602     Málaga  2017  1.630.615
603     Málaga  2016  1.629.298
604     Málaga  2015  1.628.973
605     Málaga  2014  1.621.968
606     Málaga  2013  1.652.999
607     Málaga  2012  1.641.098
608     Málaga  2011  1.625.827
609     Málaga  2010  1.609.557
610     Málaga  2009  1.593.068
611     Málaga  2008  1.563.261
612     Málaga  2007  1.517.523
613     Málaga  2006  1.491.287
614     Málaga  2005  1.453.409
```

Comment: Please provide a small sample of a .csv to reproduce the issue with your code.  Note that `UnicodeEncodeError` is often due to *printing* the data, not retrieving it.  It also looks like you are using Python 2 and if due to printing, provide the IDE environment you are using.  FYI, I ran all these commands in a Python 2 IDE and they worked fine.

Comment: P.S. use Unicode strings, not your last example.  Also it is odd your `Name_0`example prints correctly, but your `Test_0`example doesn't.  Were they run in different environments?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've added a few edits that hopefully can help!